# Как исправить ошибку Selenium Grid?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

```
public class Menu {
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        try {
            baseUrl = "https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2";

            DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ();
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver ( new URL ( "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" ), capability );
            capability.setBrowserName ( BrowserType.CHROME );
            capability.setPlatform ( Platform.MAC );
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Jan 24, 2018 8:55:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`**

*я так понимаю нужно прописать другую строку вместо DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`нужно вписать ChromeOptions()` но не выходит *

Comment: Тут, вроде как, рекомендация, а не ошибка.. А вообще капабилити нужно определить до инициализации драйвера. Переместите вызов методов `setBrowserName()` и `setPlatform()` выше `driver = `

Comment: все сделал для firefox все работает для  chrome скачал chromewebdriver все прописал не работает (

Comment: public class Menu {


     WebDriver driver;
    String  nodeURL,baseUrl;

    @Test
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

        baseUrl="http://google.com";
        nodeURL="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ();
        capability.setBrowserName ("chrome");
        capability.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL),capability);
        driver.get ( baseUrl );
        driver.quit();
    уже пытался на прямую прописать не setproperly не работает((

Comment: Так какая ошибка то? И добавляйте в вопрос (кнопка править), в комментах читать код то еще "удовольствие"